# Add feedback when awarding a bounty in the mobile theme

Tags: feature-request, bounties, mobile-web

I awarded a bounty using the mobile site, which worked great. The only thing was that when I clicked award bounty, there was no feedback to say that the bounty was successfully awarded. I only got the javascript popup to confirm. The message at the top of the screen still said there is an open bounty ending in 6 days.

When I refreshed the page, the bounty had been awarded and the message removed.

Can we get some sort of visual feedback to the user that the bounty has been awarded? Even an automatic page refresh would do.